# Visual Studio Code: Jinja Curly Braces inline for Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, python, html, visual-studio-code, jinja2

I am trying to get Jinja braces to stay in line for a javascript variable used in an apexchart.js call for a flask HTML page.

```
labels = JSON.parse({{ labels | tojson}})

data = JSON.parse({{ data | tojson}})
```

The problem I am having is that when I save the html the braces get formatted apart.

```
    labels = JSON.parse({
        {
            labels | tojson
        }
    })
    data = JSON.parse({
        {
            data | tojson
        }
    })
```

Is there away to stop Visual Studio Code from splitting the Jinja code apart?

Current Code Below:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <!-- templates/index.html -->

    {% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}

    <title>Dashboard | {{title}}</title>
    <div class="flex h-screen justify-center">
        <div id="chart" class="h-1/4 w-1/2 content-center"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
    <script>
        labels = JSON.parse({
            {
                labels | tojson
            }
        })
        data = JSON.parse({
            {
                data | tojson
            }
        })
        var options = {
            colors: ['#01ca95'],
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'sales',
                data: data
            }],
            xaxis: {
                categories: labels
            },
            yaxis: {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function(data) {
                        //Setup new Formatting class variable 
                        var Formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
                            style: 'currency',
                            currency: 'USD'
                        });

                        return Formatter.format(data);
                    }
                }
            },
        }
        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

        chart.render();
    </script>

    {% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Why on earth do you have inline scripts in your template at all? If your JS needs data, `fetch()` it from your server instead and keep Django/Jinja templating out of your scripts?